# How to control value assigned by operator []

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I know how to overload `operator[]` as follows :

```
T& operator [](int idx) {
    return TheArray[idx];
}

T operator [](int idx) const {
    return TheArray[idx];
}
```

But what I want is to control values assigned by `arr[i] = value`.
I want to control value to be between 0 and 9.
Is there any syntax to do so?

Comment: You would need to return a proxy object that wraps the element instead, and have that do the range-checking on assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by control? Do you want to fire a compile error, or do you want to throw an exception at run, or do you want to ignore assignment silently, or do you want to cut-off values if they are not in range?

Comment: @taskinoor As what we always do about classes... We'd like to throw exceptions!

Comment: Clarification question.  Do you want to do the range-checking on the result of `operator[]`, or do you want to store a range-checked T?  It would seem odd to me to have an object outside of a container that could have any value, but the object inside the container has a restricted range.  (And what happens if one inserts an object that is already out of bounds?)

Comment: It should be odd :))) I'm working on a BigNum project and I've stored each digit inside a vector of integer. You're right...  For one way I can define a class called digit and apply the bound on that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rene has provided a good answer. In addition to this, here is a full example. Note that I added a "user-defined conversion", i.e., `operator T`, in the `proxy_T` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
class myClass
{
    std::array<T, 5> TheArray; // Some array...

    class proxy_T
    {
        T& value; // Reference to the element to be modified

    public:
        proxy_T(T& v) : value(v) {}

        proxy_T& operator=(T const& i)
        {
            if (i >= 0 and i <= 9)
            {
                value = i;
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::range_error(std::to_string(i));
            }
            return *this;
        }

        operator T() // This is required for getting a T value from a proxy_T, which make the cout-lines work
        {
            return value;
        }
    };

public:
    proxy_T operator [](int const idx)
    {
        return TheArray.at(idx);
    }

    T operator [](int const idx) const
    {
        return TheArray[idx];
    }
};

int main() {
    myClass<int> A;

    std::cout << A[0] << std::endl;
    A[0] = 2;
    std::cout << A[0] << std::endl;
    A[1] = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You would have to write a template class that holds a reference to the element in the array (of type T), in this template you implement the assignment operator, and there you can implement your check. Then you return an object of this template class from your [] operator.

Something like this:

```
template< typename T> class RangeCheck
{
public:
   RangeCheck( T& dest): mDestVar( dest) { }
   RangeCheck& operator =( const T& new_value) {
      if ((0 <= new_value) && (new_value < 9)) {  // <= ??
         mDestVar = new_value;
      } else {
         ... // error handling
      }
      return *this;
   }
private:
   T&  mDestVar;
};
```